# How do the Iranian authorities or state-leaning media describe Muqtada al-Sadr?

Tags: iran, iraq

[Muqtada al-Sadr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muqtada_al-Sadr) despite being Shia seems to be leading an Iraqi faction that seems to want to be less aligned with Iran. (His supporters have recently stormed the parliament, "chanting anti-Iran curses", [according](https://youtu.be/YhLVLCdkDng?t=35) to Western media.)

I'd like to know how the Iranian authorities, from the religious to the secular, or even the state-aligned press generally talk about al-Sadr. Do they call him a heretic? A misguided nationalist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Irani media is calling him firebrand cleric as can be seen in [this article](https://www.presstv.ir/Detail/2022/07/27/686358/Sadr-supporters-storm-parliament-to-protest-PM-choice%C2%A0) by Iranian state media Presstv.

To understand the relation between Muqtada al-Sadr and Iranian authorities [this article](https://www.opendemocracy.net/en/north-africa-west-asia/iran-and-muqtada-al-sadrs-alliance-against-the-revolution-in-iraq/?ysclid=l66cxvafpb58170500) could be useful.

Comment: Interesting, but I suspect that's not the end of the story. That article is mostly adhering to Western journalism news standards, so there's hardly any subjective evaluation of those actions, which is typically not the case of statements from Iran's power figures on some other matters. It would be interesting to know if they always try to keep that tone/distance with respect to al-Sadr.